# Cannot convert java string to JSON Array in Android

Tags: java, php, android, arrays, json

Below is the query which is fetching the data from the MySql Database but the issue is that in browser it successfully outputs the data but in Android app it gives the error which is below

```
Java.Long.String Cannot Convert to JsonArray

if($stem=$con->prepare("select question from MCQs  where c_id=$c_id ")){
$stem->execute ();
$stem->bind_result($question);
$budget=array();
while($stem->fetch())
{
    $temp=array();

    $temp['question']=$question;

    array_push($budget,$temp);
}
echo json_encode($budget);
```

Below is the Android Side Java Code for the JSON

```
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    String success = jsonObject.getString("success");
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");

                    if (success.equals("1")) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            String questions = jsonObject1.getString("question").trim();
                            final String opt0ne = jsonObject1.getString("option1").trim();
                            ;
                            String opttwo = jsonObject1.getString("option2").trim();
                            ;
                            String optthree = jsonObject1.getString("option3").trim();
                            final String correctt = jsonObject1.getString("correct").trim();
```

Comment: I love a good Jason array.

Comment: _“but in Android app it gives the error which is below”_ - where? I don’t see any error.

Answer (score 0):

```
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONArray jArray = json.getJSONArray("data");
        for (int i=0;jArray.length(); i++)
        {
         JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

         //try this
         String msg= jsonObject1.getString("success"); 
       }
```